# Does CSS file sorting matter and if, why?

Tags: css, file, sorting

I have a website which uses 1 css file, it is called body.css and it consists of 841 lines. Should it be sorted in different files (header.css, footer.css page1.css, etc...), is it better in just 1 file or does it not matter?

The only thing I know for sure is sorting it in more files is a lot more readable.

Also if someone answers this I'd be most grateful for a little explanation.

Comment: Why you want to make it different? one file is ok but you will use many files in case where you are handling so many module with complex structure so in that case you don't have to worry about thousands of line..just open related css file and work. simple.

Comment: I don't want to make it different. I'd do that if it would improve the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion would be one of two things.

1) If you know that your CSS will NEVER change once you've built it, I'd build multiple CSS files in the development stage (for readability), and then manually combine them before going live (to reduce http requests)

2) If you know that you're going to change your CSS once in a while, and need to keep it readable, I would build separate files and use code (providing you're using some sort of programming language) to combine them at runtime build time (runtime minification/combination is a resource pig).

With either option I would highly recommend caching on the client side in order to further reduce http requests.

So, there are good reasons in both cases...

A solution that would allow you to get the best of both ideas would be :

1. To develop using several small CSS files

   i.e. easier to develop
   To have a build process for your application, that "combines" those files into one
       That build process could also minify that big file, btw
       It obviously means that your application must have some 
   configuration stuff that allows it to swith from "multi-files mode" to "mono-file mode".
2. And to use, in production, only the big file i.e. Single CSS

   Result : faster loading pages

maybe this will help you..

Comment: Keep in mind, there are a few good tools like SASS or Gulp (see other answers to this question) out there, which help getting separate css files together.

Comment: @JoachimSchirrmacher yes they are great, but it's not necessary to use them, when i am going for production server, i just collect all my css and put them in my Site.css

Answer (score 1):

For optimal performance it is better to have only one css file.

But for readability it would be better to have different files for different parts.

Take a look at tools like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com), which help do that without sacrifice performance. Additionally it has features to make your files even more readable by introducing variables, function and much more.

Answer (score 1):

Using more files means more requests. It will take more time to load and make unnecessary requests to the server. I'd stay with one file.

The only good reason to have other css files would be if you have third-party components, to keep them separated and be able to update them easily.

The order matters: Rules loaded later will override rules with the same name loaded before (this is valid even for rules in the same file).

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean that your website uses one CSS file? Normally you'd write your style definitions in multiple files, and they are concatenated (or not) into one file. My point is, what you are working on in your development environment should stay modular, readable, it shouldn't be influenced by what you have in production.

As for the order of the CSS files, yes, it matters, as you can overwrite your previous definitions.

For optimal caching I'd recommend you to build all the vendor CSS in one file, and your CSS in another file, versioned, so that if you change something in your code, only that file has to be updated by the browser.

But these things depend on the infrastructure. As the browsers are able now to send multiple requests simultaneously, having multiple files can lead to faster page load than only one. But I'm not sure about this.

you might want to take a look at [gulp](https://css-tricks.com/gulp-for-beginners/) to automatically optimize, and minify your CSS code.

Answer (score 1):

All css in one file is OK.
But it's free : you can make as many css file as you want. 
However usually this is how it is:

- 1 global css file for the entire page. You put the common css in here that is useful for every page on your site. You can call it app.css or style.css or mywebsite.css or any name you want.
- 1 specific css file for a specific page when you want to specially separate this css from the global css file. Because it will contains css only useful for a few pages. For example you have a special component made by your own or a special functionnality. Example : you have made a spcial javascript code working with some html for uploading some file and you want to have your code js/css separate.
- Usually, you can also have one css page for each page, but always one global css file for the entire site.

Note : Same question is also valid for javascript

Note 2 : You can also think about using a framework to minify your javascript and css into one single css / js file at the end. At work our technical boss use wro4j which works for java but it should exists many more other frameworks as you can search on google.